Issues with Tagging Slack Users in Notifications from AWS Lambda via SNS
I'm currently implementing a system that sends notifications to a Slack channel when AWS CloudWatch alarms are triggered. The notifications are sent via an SNS topic that is invoked by a Lambda function. My goal is to tag specific Slack users based on keywords in the alarm messages, but I’m encountering an issue where the users' names are printed as text instead of being tagged in Slack.
Setup Details:

AWS Components:

CloudWatch Alarms configured to invoke an SNS topic.

Lambda function that processes the alarm data and sends messages to the SNS topic.



Slack Configuration:

I’m using Slack user IDs in the format <@USER_ID> to tag users.

I have defined a mapping of keywords to Slack user IDs in my Lambda function.





import json
import boto3
import os

# Initialize the SNS client
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

# Mapping keywords to Slack user IDs
KEYWORD_TO_USER_MAPPING = {
    'elasticsearch': ['U071OPZ1H8B', 'U094F7EOA81'],
}

# Environment variable for SNS topic ARN
SNS_TOPIC_ARN = os.getenv('SNS_TOPIC_ARN', 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<account-id>:<alarm-name>')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Event received by Lambda:")
    print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    # Extract key information from the event
    alarm_name = event.get('alarmData').get('alarmName')
    new_state = event.get('alarmData').get('state').get('value')
    old_state = event.get('alarmData').get('previousState').get('value')
    state_reason = event.get('alarmData').get('state').get('reason')
    description = event.get('alarmData').get('configuration').get('description')
    region = event.get('region')

    if not alarm_name or not new_state or not state_reason:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps("Error: Missing critical information in the event.")
        }
    
    tagged_users = get_users_for_keywords(alarm_name, state_reason)
    formatted_message = create_slack_message(alarm_name, new_state, old_state, state_reason, region, tagged_users, description)
    response = publish_to_sns(formatted_message, new_state, alarm_name, region)

    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Notification sent to SNS successfully!')
        }
    else:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps(f"Failed to send notification to SNS. Response: {response}")
        }

def get_users_for_keywords(alarm_name, state_reason):
    tagged_users = []
    
    for keyword, users in KEYWORD_TO_USER_MAPPING.items():
        if keyword.lower() in (alarm_name or '').lower() or keyword.lower() in (state_reason or '').lower():
            tagged_users.extend(users)
    
    return list(set(tagged_users))

def create_slack_message(alarm_name, new_state, old_state, state_reason, region, tagged_users, description):
    tagged_user_string = ' '.join([f"<@{user}>" for user in tagged_users]) if tagged_users else 'No users tagged.'
    
    message = (
        f"- Alarm Triggered: {alarm_name}\n"
        f"- State Change: {old_state} => {new_state}\n"
        f"- Reason: {state_reason}\n"
        f"- Region: {region}\n"
        f"- Description: {description}\n"
        f"- Tagged Users: {tagged_user_string}"
    )
    
    return message

def publish_to_sns(message, new_state, alarm_name, region):
    subject_for_alarm = f'{new_state}: "{alarm_name}" ({region})'
    response = sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn=SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Message=message,
        Subject=subject_for_alarm
    )
    return response

Problem Statement:
Despite using the correct format for tagging users (i.e., <@USER_ID>), when the message is published to Slack, the user IDs appear as plain text rather than actual tags. I have verified that the Slack user IDs are correct.
How can I ensure that the tagged users are properly recognized in Slack?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!
